# Breaking change? Not receiving odata.nextLink when using odata.track-changes in Office 365 / Outlook's calendarview api?

Tags: office365api

I'm not sure when this started happening (I believe fairly recently).  This is a **breaking change** if you rely on the steps documented here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/sync-calendar-view

The issue is that the the Office 365 & Outlook.com calendarview api no longer seems to return a @odata.nextLink when there is more data to be fetched if you specify "odata.track-changes" for the "Prefer" header in your request.

Here is a CURL request to repro the issue... be sure make the request authenticated as a user with at least 50 events during the time frame specified (to trigger paging).

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <OMITTED>" -H "Accept: application/json; odata.metadata=none" -H "Prefer: odata.track-changes" "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendarview?startdatetime=2016-06-16T00:00:00Z&enddatetime=2017-06-23T00:00:00Z"
```

When I make this request, the resulting response has 10 entries (even though there are at least 50 events) and the response does not have an @odata.nextLink.   It does have a @odata.deltaLink however.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it has always worked this way. The initial sync returns a `deltaLink` instead of a `nextLink`. You have to treat that initial sync request specially and go ahead and issue the next request using the `deltaToken`.

> 1. Initial sync request: The very first sync request sets up the sync state.
> 2. Initial sync response:
>
>    - Check for "Preference-Applied: odata.track-changes" in the response header to confirm a successful sync attempt and the resource supports synchronization.
>    - If the sync attempt was successful, **the initial response always contains an @odata.deltaLink with a deltaToken value**. If the response contains any data, save the deltaToken value for the second request.
>    - If the initial response wasn't successful, or doesn't return any data indicating there are no events in the specified calendar view, this round of sync ends.
> 3. Subsequent sync request: Use the deltaToken or skipToken value from the previous request to issue the next request. See the second and third sync requests as examples.
> 4. Subsequent sync response:
>
>    - If the response returns any data, and, there is more data to sync in that time range, the response would include an @odata.nextLink and a skipToken value. Save the skipToken for the next sync request.
>    - Go back to step 3, follow the nextLink, if any, apply the corresponding skipToken value in the next sync request, and follow any subsequent nextLink, until you have synchronized all the data in the time range for that calendar.
> 5. Final sync response: When all events in the calendar view are synchronized, the final response in this round would include an @odata.deltaLink and a deltaToken again. Save the deltaToken value for the next round of synchronization.

Comment: Thanks @jason-johnston!  That explains it.  Now it's a schrödinbug on our side.  Thanks!

Comment: @jason-johnston can it be that microsoft graph does not support sync requests? I have the same issue like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39518853/2491336)

Comment: No, Graph supports sync. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_overview

Comment: Thank you, @JasonJohnston! Please, please consider updating the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/calendar-rest-operations#SyncCalendarView. It's terrible in explaining this flow!